# How to specify SQL comments through EclipseLink Annotations?

Tags: java, documentation, persistence, eclipselink

Is there any way to specify SQL comments through EclipseLink specific annotations?

Comments for tables and columns.

According to [How to specify SQL comments through JPA annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807676/how-to-specify-sql-comments-through-jpa-annotations) there is no way to do this via JPA. But maybe there is an EclipseLink specific way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the EclipseLink developers](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg05529.html), there is currently no way to archive this, even not with proprietary methods.