# JPA column annotation description

Tags: java, jpa

In the JPA Column annotation, how can I add some comments or description to that column ? just like

```
@Column(name="total", description="This field is only for CEO")
Integer total;
```

And this description will be added to generated table DDL automatically.

is it possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can not do it through annotations. Check out this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807676/how-to-specify-sql-comments-through-jpa-annotations

Comment: thanks. then we have to find another way.